# C program why does it crash after i input

Tags: c

I'm having some issues getting my input to go in, it crashes right after I enter the itemID, I'm completely lost and I working with arrays if anyone could help me that would be truly amazing. Also thanks, I know my coding is crap.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 3

//Structed Items

struct item{

char itemname[20];
char itemdes[30];
int itemID;
int itemOH;
double itemUP;
};


// Function Declarations

int getMenu_Choice ();
int process (int choice, int count, struct item inven[]);
    int add (int count, struct item inven[]);
int showall(int count, struct item inven[]);


int main (void)
{ // OPENS MAIN


//  Declarations

int choice;
int count;
struct item inven[MAX];


// Statements

do//
{   
choice = getMenu_Choice ();
process (choice, count, inven);
}
while (choice != 0);


return 0;


} // CLOSE MAIN

/*============================getChoice=*/

int getMenu_Choice (void)
{ //OPEN GETCHOICE


// Declarations
int choice;

// Statements

printf("\n\n**********************************");
printf("\n             MENU             ");
printf("\n\t1.Create A File          ");
printf("\n\t2.Read A File           ");
printf("\n\t0.Exit                    ");
printf("\n**********************************");
printf("\nPlease Type Your Choice Using 0-2");
printf("\nThen Hit Enter: ");
scanf("%d", &choice);

return choice;

} //CLOSES GET CHOICE




/*============================process=*/

int process (int choice, int count, struct item inven[])
{// OPEN PROCESS 


// Declarations


// Statements
switch(choice)
    {
        case 1: count = add(count, inven);
            break;
        case 2: showall(count, inven);
            break;
        case 0: exit;
            break;
        deafult: printf("Sorry Option Not Offered");
            break;

} // switch

return count;

} // CLOSE PROCESS


/*============================add one=*/
int add(int count, struct item inven[])

{//OPENS CREATE

// Declarations

int i;


i = count;

 if (count != MAX) 
{
printf("Enter the Item ID:\n");
scanf("%d", &inven[i].itemID);

printf("Enter the Item Name:\n");
scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemname);
i++;

}

else {
printf("sorry there is no more room for you to add");

};

return i;


}; // CLOSE CREATE



/*============================showall=*/

int showall(int count, struct item inven[])
{
//Declarations
int i;

// Statements




for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
printf("\nItem ID   : %d", inven[i].itemID);
printf("\nItem Name  : %s", inven[i].itemname);
};    

return 0;
}
```

Comment: `count` is used uninitialized in `add`.  Also, `count = add(count, inven);` in `process` does not update the `count` variable in `main`.

Comment: Ok so what do you suggest I do?

Comment: 1) `int count;` --> `int count = 0;`

Comment: 2) `process (choice, count, inven);` --> `count = process (choice, count, inven);`

Comment: 3) `i < MAX` --> `i < count`

Comment: 4) `scanf("%s", &inven[i].itemname);` --> `scanf("%s", inven[i].itemname);`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a seg fault due to uninitialized variable "count" being used to access an array, resulting in you going beyond the bounds of the array.

You are assuming count has a certain value (0?) but in fact it has whatever garbage happens to be their when you create the variable. You need to explicitly say count = 0;

Comment: So I made all the changes suggested ahead like initializing the declarations in main, then changing the if statement in add and it still crashed after I hit enter on the item ID

Comment: copy and paste the code you submitted. Change only the line 32 to initialize count to 0. Recompile and try your input. This single change allowed me to run your program fine, so I am unsure what has changed since then.

Comment: So I missed line 32, but made all the other changes, now it works, HOWEVER, when I add three which is the max it doesn't reject me when I go add a fourth one so now I'm having issues saving into the array,

Comment: You increment i in your add function, and return its value. This returned value is caught in your process functions switch structure and is then returned. BUT the line that calls process from main, does not catch this return of count. So the version of count that is in the main scope, never changes. Their are lots of ways to fix this, the easiest would be to update line 32 of your code such that count is set equal to the return value of the process function call.

Comment: how would I do that that? int count = process

Comment: within main, where you call the function called process, in the do-while loop. Rather then just calling process you need to set count equal to the call of process:  count = process (choice, count, inven); This way, count gets updated with your return value.

Answer (score 0):

> In the ***main*** function, ***count*** declared but not initialized so ***count*** have meaningless value,you must initialize to ***count*** variable to 0

```
int main (void)
{ // OPENS MAIN


//  Declarations

int choice;
int count;        // --->>>> int count = 0;
struct item inven[MAX];
//...
}
```